# Lua Array Deep Array search for Open Tibia Script

Tags: arrays, lua

Looking to get info from an array inside an array, without having exact info basically.

```
    local cfg_raids = {
    [2] =
    {
        ["10:17"] = {
            raidName = "Rats - Thais",
            Event_Type = "Raid Activated",
            Storage = 1234,
            alreadyExecuted = false
        },
        ["10:20"] = {
            raidName = "Testing this shit",
            Event_Type = "Raid Activated",
            Storage = 1235,
            alreadyExecuted = false
        },
    },
    [3] =
    {
        ["12:00"] = {
            raidName = "OrcsThais",
            Event_Type = "Raid Activated",
            Storage = 1236,
            alreadyExecuted = false
        },
    },
```

Trying to Grab the time randomly without actually having the exact time stamp.

So like when the script activates the timestamp array ["10:17"] it grabs all the next arrays info ["10:20"] without actually knowing the ["10:20"]

OPEN TIBIA INFORMATION: http://otland.net/threads/looking-for-some-assistance-on-a-script.216303/

Answer (score 2):

With non-integer keys like that you can't really do it. You can try using the `next` function to get the next key from your current key but you have no guarantees which next key you will get if there are more than two keys in the table (you can not even guarantee that it will be consistently the same next key).

You could use integer indices in that table and make time a field of the table and then simply use the next integer as your next key if that works however.

You could also store the times used as keys, in whatever order you want, in the integer indices in the table (or some other table) and use that without needing to redo the table itself (e.g. `cfg_raids = { [2] = { "10:17", "10:20", ["10:17"] = {...}, ["10:20"] = {...} } }`).

Comment: oh, thats what i kinda figured, too bad theres not a way to use like 0-10000  ect  for calling the place, so you could use a for statement, thats the only thing i could think would of been really possible, but is there a way to do that?, like call the first, then the second, ect... places of an array / table

Comment: Hm? You can absolutely use a loop to walk a table index-by-index. Either manually `for i = 1,#tab do ... end` or using `ipairs` (`for i, v in ipairs(tab) do ... end`).

Comment: Tryed using both of those, still couldn't get them to read from the first posted table / array.

`for i,line in ipairs(cfg_raids) do
        pre_text = pre_text .. '\n '.. line
end`

Comment: The `cfg_raids` table in your original post is not an "array" in lua terms as it does not have contiguous keys from 1..n. As such ipairs is not, strictly, defined to operate over it. Also, your `line` variable there would contain a table not a string if it had been working. Try `local c = { {raidName = "raid 1"}, {raidName = "raid 2"} }; for i, raid in ipairs(c) do print(raid.raidName) end' just as an example.

Comment: @EtanReisner i'd suggest using `pairs` instead of `ipairs`, because the latter would stop at the first non-integer key, as it's designed for integer indexed arrays, while `pairs` is designed for any non-nil-indexed table.

Comment: @nonchip I didn't suggest using `ipairs` (I just mentioned that it works). I also explained why the non-working code from the `OP` that used it wasn't working (directly in my comment and indirectly in my answer). And `pairs` is semantically different enough in operation that it doesn't work for the purpose here since order does matter.

Comment: @EtanReisner ok, as order matters, i guess the most error-proof option would be parsing the data into e.g. timestamps and looping over them, but that somehow feels wrong too :D

Comment: The mixed keys/array indices option is, I think, the best option and is one that I've used on numerous occasions. Assuming you need to access the entries by timestamp in the first place.